# Use javascript to check if logged in with devise

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, cookies, devise

I have a rails 3 app using devise for authentication, and want to use javascript to see if a user is logged in. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: please add more details to get better advice

Comment: what further details could be necessary? I use devise for authentication in my app, and want to know how to check if a user is authenticated using javascript?

Comment: @Solomon: I don't know how Rails works, but you can check for cookies (PHP) or hidden input (ASP.NET) to see the session id.

Comment: Normally you wouldn't use client-side code to see if the user is logged in on the server, you would just do that on the server, and include some javascript with whatever login details need to be made available on the client.

Comment: I want to use client side code so I can cache the page, and then use javascript to possibly change the header to the logged in or logged out version

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since Devise is based on Warden, you can use Warden's callbacks to set an additional cookie that will be visible from js (unlike the server only session cookie), e.g in your devise.rb:

```
  Warden::Manager.after_set_user do |user,auth,opts|
    auth.cookies[:signed_in] = 1
  end

  Warden::Manager.before_logout do |user,auth,opts|
    auth.cookies.delete :signed_in
  end
```

Comment: @SsouLlesS Almost. I had to change the delete line (for some reason, `cookies.delete` was not removing the cookie from browser. I assigned `0` as `value` and `expire` to `Time.now` on logout.

Answer (score -2):

It looks like Rails stores session on the client in the [cookies](http://www.quarkruby.com/2007/10/21/sessions-and-cookies-in-ruby-on-rails#sinrails).

I'd check for the cookies in your application when you're logged in (`console.log( document.cookies )`) and see what's there that is *not* there when you're logged out.

This way, you'll easily see how to check whether you're connected or not on the client.

Comment: this is what I get when I check the document.cookie, and it doesn't make a difference if it's logged in or logged out: __utma=111872281.2045911381.1309470856.1334590129.1334935149.157; __utmz=111872281.1309470856.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __utmc=111872281

Comment: The devise cookies are HttpOnly meaning you can't read them from javascript. For this to work I think you would need to set your own cookie.